# Anchor tags in URL being crawled by Nutch

Tags: nutch

For some reason nutch is crawling URLs with the anchor tag (#). I even updated the regex-filter to not include the # in URLs during the crawl, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas what may be going on?

Comment: URL filters are applied after URL normalization. The default URL normalization rules strip the anchors from the URLs. This means that anchor tags do not cause duplicates but also that you cannot filter on them.

Comment: I'm running Nutch 1.8, but don't have a grasp on how to debug what's going on. Are you saying that the default normalization rules are being overriden somewhere which is why the anchor tags aren't being stripped?

Comment: Yes, with the default configuration anchors are stripped from URLs.